# Showing error in notification

Tags: android, android-service, android-logcat

I'm trying to get the notification upon getting update. I tried it in a seperate module and it worked. But when I tried to include it in a package, it is showing the error saying that.

```
01-18 09:54:27.020: E/MediaPlayerService(33): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
01-18 09:54:27.121: E/MediaPlayer(1460): Unable to to create media player
01-18 09:54:27.260: E/RingtoneManager(1460): Failed to open ringtone content://settings/system/notification_sound
```

I thought it is with the notification sound and I commented it. Even after making so, I'm getting same above error.

Update.java

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(UpdateService.this,NewsActivity.class);
                            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(UpdateService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                            Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "new update arrived", System.currentTimeMillis());
                            n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Update", "new update arrived", pIntent);
                            n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                            NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            NM.notify(id,n);
//                          try{
//                              Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
//                              Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
//                              r.play();
//                          }catch(Exception e){
//                              e.printStackTrace();
//                          }    
                            Log.d("Change","the old value changed");
                        }else{
                                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                        }                       
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        isRunning = false;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I'm a budding android developer. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to play the sound yourself - Android will handle it for you.

Remove the try/catch block with the RingtoneManager and you should be fine.

If you're not getting a notification sound or would like to change it, see the [Notification.sound](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#defaults) field.

I suggest you use `notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL`.